# Как парсить JSON файл в CoreData

Tags: json, objective-c

Всем привет, подскажите как парсить JSON файл такого формата:

```
{ 
"Ukraine":["Kiev","Vyshhorod","Ternopil","Brody","Donetsk"], 
"Romania":["PiteÅŸti","Bucharest","BacÄƒu","Roman"], 
"Lebanon":["Beirut","Zgharta","Bsalim"] 
}
```

в CoreData (ObjC)?

Comment: По-моему в вопросе маловато приведено информации. Вам нужно данный JSON представить в виде любой сущности для CoreData? Или у Вас уже есть какая-то структура в CoreData и Вы хотите её заполнить на основе приведённого JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Преобразовать JSON в словарь NSMutableDictionary а затем уже полученные данные присвоить соответствующим полям объектов coredata и сохранить контекст.

```
    NSString *json = @"{"
"\"Ukraine\":[\"Kiev\",\"Vyshhorod\",\"Ternopil\",\"Brody\",\"Donetsk\"],"
"\"Romania\":[\"PiteÅŸti\",\"Bucharest\",\"BacÄƒu\",\"Roman\"],"
"\"Lebanon\":[\"Beirut\",\"Zgharta\",\"Bsalim\"]"
"}";

NSError* error;
NSData *data = [json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// Преобразуем данные в словарь
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

NSLog(@"%@", [dictionary description]);

// Работаем со словарем
NSArray *keys = [dictionary allKeys];

for (int i = 0; i < keys.count; i++) {
    NSString *key = keys[i];
    NSArray *values = dictionary[key];
    NSLog(@"key: %@ values: %@", key, [values description]);
}
```